# Relationship redundant?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm designing a database and I have a user table with users, and a group table with user's group.

These groups will have a **owner** (a user that has created it), and a set of users that are part of the group (like a Whatsapp group).

To represent this I have this design:

[image]

**Do you think the `owner` column on `Group` table is necessary?** Maybe I can add an `owner` column on `Group` table I can know easily the group's owner.

Comment: It is ok to have owner field in Group table. But as option you can have flag in UserGroup table "isOwner".

Comment: @SergeyNLukin Lol, did we even think in the same column name? :)

Comment: it means we are using same books for education :)

Comment: Your current design allows an owner that is not a member of the group she owns. Is that acceptable?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic No, this is not acceptable.

Comment: Are name conflicts between users an groups allowed?

Comment: @geomagas name conflicts? I don't understand.

Comment: I mean, if there's a user named `foo`, can there also be a _group_ named `foo`?

Comment: @geomagas I think so.

Comment: But you don't _know for sure_? Let me explain: Should you decide to apply authorization rules on objects (ACLs) to users _and_ groups, how would you distinguish if you're granting privileges to user `foo` or group `foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't add the `owner` in the `group` then where are you going to add it? The only way I see apart from this is adding a boolean `isowner` to the `usergroup`. Anyway, this would not make sense if there will only be 1 owner. If there can be `N` owners then that would be the way to go.

Comment: Only one user can be the owner.

Comment: Yeap. I covered both options there.

Comment: So, you prefer an owner column on group table, isn't it?

Comment: But my current design allows an owner that is not a member of the group she owns.

Comment: That is a data issue. Should be most likely solved in your application layer or by applying constraints in a DBMS (not related to database design). If you go for the `N` owner solution using only `1` owner that will be solved too. However, you will then ask "But how can I make sure there will only be `1` owner?" And I will answer `That is a data issue` :)

Comment: You've convinced me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need 4 tables:

- User
- UserGroup
- Group
- UserRole (associated with UserGroup) - Shows the role of a user in a group (admin/owner, etc.) - If your roles are Admin and Ordinary user, you could use a Binary column on UserGroup instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but you'll need one more step to ensure an owner must actually belong to the group she owns:

[image]

There is a FOREIGN KEY in Group {groupID, owner} that references UserGroup {groupID, userID}.

If your DBMS supports deferred foreign keys, you can make owner NOT NULL, to ensure a group cannot be owner-less. Otherwise you can leave it NULL-able (and you will still be able to break the "chicken-and-egg" problem with circular references if your DBMS supports [MATCH SIMPLE](http://wiki.burnsoft.net/KB58.ashx?NoRedirect=1) FKs - almost all do).

Comment: Well, now I have to know how to implement it using `Entity Framework Code First`. By the way, I'm using Sql Server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know a solution has already been proposed, but I am so convinced there is a better one ...

At the higher level, the concept of owner can be seen ***as a property of the relation existing between users and groups***. It should then ideally be set as ***a field in the UserGroup table***.

It could be either a boolean field or, even better, a generalized `userGroupNatureOfRelation` field, that could hold values such as 'owner', 'participant', 'user', or whatever could be the status.

Of course, such a solution allows you to implement any specific business rule, like 'there is only one owner per group'. It will let you implement any other more sophisticated business rule when needed, and it will even allow you to add a level of complexity by adding fields such as:

- `userGroupRelationStartDate`
- `userGroupRelationEndDate`

where you'll be able to follow the nature of the relation between a group and a person through time ...

Of course you could say 'I don't need it'. But implementing such an 'open' model does not cost anything more than what you are thinking of now. Then, if for any reason, in a near or far future, business rules have to be changed or improved, your model stays valid and efficient ...

This said, building views and manipulating data should be a lot easier with this model. So this a good and immediate reason to adopt it!